Topologically conjugate linear flows implies hyperbolic linear vector field.
Suppose $A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d,\,\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a linear vector field with the property that its linear flow $(e^{tA})_t$ is topologically conjugate to every linear flow $(e^{tB})_t$, for $B$ close to $A$. Show that A is hyperbolic, that is, no eigenvalue of $A$ is purely imaginary.
My attempt was to derive a contradiction: If A is not hyperbolic, there is at least two eigenvalues $\pm i\beta$ of $A$ with $\beta\neq0$, since complex eigenvalues come in pairs. Even so in every open ball around it there are infinitely many hyperbolic linear vector fields, due to the latter form an open and dense subset of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^d,\,\mathbb{R^d})$.
Then we can take $\epsilon>0$ and $B\in B_{\epsilon}(A)$ such that $B$ is hyperbolic and, by hypothesis, the linear flows $(e^{tA})_t$ and $(e^{tB})_t$ are topologically conjugate. As $B$ is hyperbolic, there is a decomposition $\mathbb{R}^d=E_B^s\oplus E_B^u$ into stable and unstable subspaces, both of which are invariant and the eigenvalues of the restriction of $B$ to $E_B^s$ and $E_B^u$ are, respectively, the eigenvalues of $B$ with negative and positive real parts.
I tried using the following theorem to get the contradiction:

But it needs both vectors fields to be hyperbolic to start with... Then after, I tried using the previous exercise, that says the set of hyperbolic vector fields with fixed dimension of the stable subspace (stability index) is open, but again I couldn't manage to prove what I needed.
I'd appreciate any help or hint.
